# Mount azure blob storage as a drive in Linux

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to mount an Azure blob account as a drive in a linux machine, and have the files show up as file blobs in the Azure portal?  I know I can mount an Azure blob as a disk, but when I'm done, I just have a disk.  I'm looking to backup a few critical files from an Azure VM, and don't really want to rig up SDK calls.  I'd rather a cron rsync a directory -- added benefit: it prunes.  I'm familiar with [rclone](https://rclone.org/azureblob/) and [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy), but both require I bake azure secrets into the command line.  Is there a blob mount way to do it instead of a separate install?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) to mount a Blob storage container on Linux and access data. Blobfuse is a virtual file system driver for Azure Blob Storage, which allows you to access your existing block blob data in your Storage account through the Linux file system. Azure Blob Storage is an object storage service and therefore does not have a hierarchical namespace. Blobfuse provides this namespace using the virtual directory scheme with the use of forward-slash '/' as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

there is Mount for Files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction

Do not try Mount with Windows SMB DISASTER!!!

Mount Azure File storage on Linux VMs using SMB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mount-azure-file-storage-on-linux-using-smb

ONE MORE TIME  SMB= DISASTER!!!!

there are 3rd party tools like for BLOBs
https://www.cloudberrylab.com/

https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup/linux.aspx

personally I look to develop by myself app and backup on demand not as permanent disk attached Hard to secure...

READ HERE
https://www.google.ca/search?q=hack+smb+share

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying SMB is bad always (and thus don't use Azure Files) or that SMB is bad if mounting to Windows, but mounting to Linux is ok?  (It feels like the vulnerability would be in the SMB sharing, not in the way it's mounted.)

Comment: I'd say he's just fear mongering. Assuming you secure your account with solid credentials, I'm sure MS has  done everything to secure the SMB endpoint since it's exposed to the world as such.

Comment: well is need to open 445 port, that that is cause the attacks I will use Azure Files but I will develop by myself application which do the backup connect only when I need to copy the files from API  . I did research and these SMB is disaster somewhere I found a link from OWASP to not use it  but here some other https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2017/01/16/SMB-Security-Best-Practices

Comment: one more https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enCA751CA752&ei=iXIpW4X1MKTGjwS2trsg&q=port+445+vulnerability&oq=445+port&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.3539.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.mdZsEwZbcSE

Answer (score 0):

[goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) added support for azure blob: https://github.com/kahing/goofys/blob/master/README-azure.md#azure-blob-storage